# aws-cli schedule-run ArgumentException error

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use Bash to run aws-cli devicefarm schedule-run to run instrumentation testing:

```
TEST_STRUCTURE=type\=INSTRUMENTATION,testPackageArn=$TESTS_UPLOAD_ARN

aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn $PROJECT_ARN --app-arn $APP_UPLOAD_ARN --device-pool-arn $DEVICE_POOL_ARN --test $TEST_STRUCTURE
```

But keep receiving an error:

```
A client error (ArgumentException) occurred when calling the ScheduleRun operation: Missing or unprocessed resources.
```

How can I resolve this error, I'm not sure what values I am not passing correctly...

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Initially I thought it was caused by the uploaded APK files not being processed yet (see the status field in the [list-uploads](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-uploads.html) command, but even when the status is SUCCEEDED the problem occurs.

Comment: P.S. to whomever downvoted the question; when you downvote, please leave a comment to the poster on why you downvoted their post. Only by giving them feedback will they ever know how to improve their (next) questions.

Comment: Hi Thomas, that's good thinking, I already check that the status of each APK is successful before moving onto this part of the code though, but I'll look into list-uploads, ty

Comment: Hey Jordan, any news? I haven't had a lot of time to look into the problem, but I haven't found the cause (or a solution) yet. I hope you've had more luck ;)

Comment: Negative, adding the --debug to the command gives you more info, but I haven't found the root yet